# Path-like mark at scrollbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement [Path-like](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/path/id403639508?mt=8) time mark for android. I found some guides on how to implement that on ListView, but I need to do that for RecyclerView with differently sized items in it. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used really easy and stupid method to achieve smooth animation of time path-like mark. We ignore real position of scrollbar, since it's hard to get and it tends to change it's size and position drastically based on content size.
In OnScrolled method of RecyclerView we recalculated and reset margins of view based on `dy` - amout pixels been scrolled. Here is what code looks like now:

```
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy == 0) return;
                if (dy < 0) {
                    if ((botMarg - dy) >= displayHeight - topOffset) {
                        botMarg = displayHeight - topOffset;
                    } else {
                        botMarg -= dy;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (botMarg - dy <= botOffset) {
                        botMarg = botOffset;
                    } else {
                        botMarg -= dy;
                    }
                }
```

To get current view we used method `recyclerView.findChildViewUnder()` with position we got in OnScrolled.